# How can we add a date picker in a date field exposed filter?

Tags: views, datetime

In Drupal 8 am trying to add date pickup popup calendar in our custom search form. Search Page is created by Views page and adding DOB field
by the date field expose.

But there is no option to add date popup calendar in views. While date pop up calendar is showing in the "Add Content" page in admin area.

Any idea how can we show datepicker calendar on date field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the contrib module [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters). At the 'Exposed form' settings in your view you can select 'Better Exposed Filters' after enabling BEF. After selecting the exposed form method you should have more options per field, a datepicker is one of them (on date fields).

Answer (score 1):

This is a discussion in [Use form element of type date instead textfield when selecting a date in an exposed filter](https://www.drupal.org/node/2648950).

> **Problem/Motivation**
>
> When adding a datetime exposed filter I cannot simply select a date -
>   I have to manually enter a date which is very bad UX.

I have installed the patch [#71](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2648950-71.patch) with Drupal 8.2.6 and it works.